# SQL Server reverse order after using desc

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to reverse the order in SQL Server of results after using desc. For example:

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC
```

returns results:

```
505
504
503
```

But then I want to flip the results to look like this:

```
503
504
505
```

I tried

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 3 * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC) ORDER BY id ASC
```

But that did not work. How can I fix it?

Comment: When you say "did not work", *how* did it not work? Did it give you different results? Did it give you the same results (wrong order)? Did the server explode? Did raptors invade your office?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That should work as long as you alias the subquery.

```
SELECT q.* 
    FROM (SELECT TOP 3 * 
              FROM table 
              ORDER BY id DESC) q
    ORDER BY q.id ASC
```

Comment: What are the performance implications of nesting reverse ordering like this?

Comment: @SamMalayek That is certainly easy enough to set up and test yourself.

Comment: lol @JoeStefanelli true. theoretically, since it's an indexed field and btree has a cheap time complexity of O(log N), doubling the ordering shouldn't make much difference. I'll make a note to test this out one day.

Answer (score 6):

I think you forgot the subselect alias

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 3 * 
    FROM table 
    ORDER BY id DESC
) s
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 3 * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC) As AliasName ORDER BY id ASC`

Answer (score 2):

```
;WITH cte
AS
(
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id DESC) rank
   FROM table
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte
WHERE rank <= 3 
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: Just a question.  Won't this CTE select the whole table and only when you do the outer select will it filter the rows you want?  Is this not potentially expensive for large tables?  Maybe, I'm wrong and the CTE is not executed until the outer select is executed, a bit like deferred execution.

Comment: @SachinKainth - No SQL Server will add a `TOP` to the plan anyway. This should have `ORDER BY id ASC` as the final order by though.

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 3 * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC) AS r ORDER BY r.id ASC
```

I figured it out. I needed to make a temporary table and have a name using AS.

Comment: What do you mean by "AS" (in this context)?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM table
    ORDER BY ID DESC
) TMP
ORDER BY TMP.ID ASC
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.