# MYSQL: How Do I Show Sort Table from Last to First?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, jquery-ui-sortable

How Do I Show Sort Table from Last to First?
Show in the Website

Namely:

```
id

5
4
3
2
1
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html

Comment: Use the `ORDER BY` clause with the `DESC` option to make it descending.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sql server reverse order after using desc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534248/sql-server-reverse-order-after-using-desc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using ORDER BY in your query.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

Comment: Thanks, 
problem solved - 
Sorry.
The first is my ask,  
The search did not find