# Order by DESC reverse result

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I'm retrieving some data in SQL, order by DESC. I then want to reverse the result. I was doing this by pushing the data into an array and then using *array_reverse*, but I am finding it's quite taxing on CPU time and would like to simply use the correct SQL query.

I've looked at this thread *[SQL Server reverse order after using desc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534248/sql-server-reverse-order-after-using-desc#_=_)*, but I cannot seem to make it work with my query.

```
SELECT live.message,
       live.sender,
       live.sdate,
       users.online
FROM live, users
WHERE users.username = live.sender
ORDER BY live.id DESC
LIMIT 15
```

Comment: What is "array_reverse"? A PHP function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap your query with another query and order by with `asc`. Since you want to order by `live.id`, you must include it in the inner query so the outer one can sort by it:

```
SELECT   message, sender, sdate, online 
FROM     (SELECT   live.message, live.sender, live.sdate, users.online, live.id 
          FROM     live, users
          WHERE    users.username = live.sender 
          ORDER BY live.id DESC 
          LIMIT    15) t
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

You can place your query into a subquery and then reverse the order:

```
SELECT t.message,
       t.sender,
       t.sdate,
       t.online
FROM
(
    SELECT live.id,
           live.message,
           live.sender,
           live.sdate,
           users.online
    FROM live
    INNER JOIN users
        ON users.username = live.sender
    ORDER BY live.id DESC
    LIMIT 15
) t
ORDER BY t.id ASC
```

You'll notice that I replaced your implicit `JOIN` with an *explicit* `INNER JOIN`.  It is generally considered undesirable to use commas in the `FROM` clause (q.v. the ANSI-92 standard) because it makes the query harder to read.